# Twitter integration the way Klout works

Tags: twitter

I'm designing a service similar to Klout, this is, the user's twitter account is scanned continuously in order to update some sort of metric which is the added value of my service. For this to work my app needs to be approved by the user, but I'm a little bit confused on what to do next. How I ( efficiently ) manage to keep my service in synch with user's new tweets after he/she has approved the app from the first time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions assuming you have a user's OAuth tokens:

1. Poll the user's friends/followers/timeline everyday and analyze it w/ the REST API. Beware of rate-limit limitations.
2. Use the streaming API to get this data in realtime and then analyze.

I'm sure you'll want to use #2. Create a listener that receives the push events from twitter and then store it and run your business logic analysis on it later.

The data model you will use and prescience (DB) depend on what business logic you need to run.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm more worried about scalability ( my service could eventually be used bi millions) than updates being in realtime, so I'm tempted for #1. What about the token? once obtained, they are work forever?

Comment: Well the docs on the streaming API don't say there is any limit on the number of people you can subscribe to so I'd just use that!

Comment: Regarding Oauth: I think twitter oauth's last forever. I know that facebook's tokens don't unless the user grants that permission on the permission dialog. But I think twitters are good...